# Wooden garden house infested with small white mites

Tags: repair, wood, gazebo

The wooden gazebo/house is infested with white small bugs.  See the picture.
Are they wooden mites? Are they harmless or?
How would be best way to get rid of them?

Structure is next to small pond so moisture is possible

Location central europe.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there are no plants close and if you're careful not to get any in your pond (if you have fish or water plants)... You can add a small amount of Dawn dish soap with water in a spray bottle to kill them. This will kill just about everything and do it quickly. If the white flies aren't dropping immediately add some more dish soap. This works on ants, wasps, spiders and more usually with one squirt. Just don't get it on any plants you like as it will kill them too.